# Bash cUrl response converted to string - won't match 'identical' string in string comparison

Tags: string, bash, curl, digital-ocean

```
while [[ "$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/$NEW_ID" | jq '.droplet.status')" != "active" ]]; do                         
    echo "$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/$NEW_ID" | jq '.droplet.status')"                                            
    echo "try again"                                                                                       
    sleep 30s                                                                                              
done
```

The echo command outputs "active" appropriately (once the Droplet is active), but the while statement always fails.

After looking at other questions on SO about bash string comparisons I've tried quotation marks/no quotation marks around each side of the comparison operator and using * to match for possible newlines but the problem persists.

In an attempt to get exactly what is getting echo'd I piped the output to od.
This is what I got:

```
0000000 " a c t i v e " \n 0000011
```

I can see the newline after the string but "active"*, "active*", active*, and " a c t i v e "*(I was getting desperate here) did not successfully match when they should have. What am I missing?

Comment: `set -x` (or `bash -x yourscript`) is your friend. Which is to say -- let the shell itself describe to you what the comparison operation it's doing is.

Comment: BTW, you don't need quotes on the left-hand side of a comparison in `[[ ]]`, as string-splitting and globbing is already suppressed in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jq` without `-r` will be returning not `active` but `"active"`, since its output is escaped as JSON data. However, in your comparison, the quotes on the right-hand side are *syntactic* -- parsed as shell syntax, not data -- so the shell is comparing the output of your pipeline to `active`, a string which doesn't contain any quotes.

Two approaches come immediately to mind:

- Include literal rather than syntactic quotes on the right-hand side of the comparison:

  ```
  [[ $(curl ... | jq ...) = '"active"' ]] # option 1: outer single quotes
  [[ $(curl ... | jq ...) = \"active\" ]] # option 2: escape the double quotes
  ```
- Use the `-r` argument to `jq` to emit raw strings, thereby suppressing quotes in its output:

  ```
  [[ $(curl ... | jq -r ...) = active ]]
  ```